# What is the best way to ask for a coloring of a grid where no sub-rectangle has all of the same colors?

Tags: combinatorics, or-tools, sat

I have an m by n rectangular grid with c possible colors for each gridpoint.  I want to use OR-Tools to find a valid coloring.  What is the best way to do it?

I was thinking that it might be adding an OnlyEnforceIf clause for each pair of columns per row (based on color assignment equality), and then asserting that if an aligned pair in two different rows are also equal, then the two pairs cannot have the same color.

However, this seems very verbose, and introduces a lot of new variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create

color[x, y, c] a boolean var that is true of point (x, y) has color c.

then add the constraints:

Each point has exactly one color

```
for each (x, y): 
    sum over c color[x, y, c] == 1
```

Any rectangle is not uni color:

```
for each x1, y1, x2, y2, c:   # (x2 > x1, y2 > y1)
    BoolOr(color[x1, y1, c].Not(),
           color[x1, y2, c].Not(),
           color[x2, y1, c].Not(),
           color[x2, y2, c].Not())
```